# Custom sort order in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

Am I able to define my own sort order and still use the Python sort function? For example, say my desired sorting order is:

```
list1 = ['Stella', 'Bob', 'Joe', 'Betty']
```

I'd hoped to do something like:

```
list2 = ['Joe', 'Stella']
sorted(list2, key=list1)
```

and get:

```
['Stella', 'Joe']
```

where the sorted order stays within the custom order in `list1`. I can do it in multiple steps by swapping out for numeric values but thought there may be a way to do it similar to above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use a lambda in the sorted function. Just supply it the `index` function of `list1`:

```
sorted(list2, key=list1.index)
```

Comment: This is not very efficient, but quick to write and good enough for most use cases.

Answer (score 5):

Note that for the example you have given you are wasting time sorting `list2` as you can simply use the already sorted `list1` if the items in `list2` are unique:

```
print([e for e in list1 if e in list2])
```

should print

```
['Stella', 'Joe']
```

To improve it even more, you can use a `set` for faster lookups:

```
set2 = set(list2)
print([e for e in list1 if e in set2])
```

This second variant works in `O(n)` which is faster than any sorting algorithm.

**Edit:** The answers given by [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63107620/2011147) and [Jab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63107677/2011147) are close to `O(n*m + n*log n)`. This is a `O(n * log n)` solution that works for non-unique cases:

```
lookup_dict = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(list1)}
print(sorted(list2, key=lookup_dict.get))
```

Comment: Subject to the unique caveat this is a great solution.

Comment: @Selcuk, In my particular case, they won't always be unique, which is why I marked answer below. Nice method though in unique case.

Comment: @sobrio35 Fair enough. I have added an alternative solution which should work in all cases for future reference.

Comment: I've shown an O(n) solution that works for non-unique cases

Answer (score 2):

If `list1` and `list2` are both guaranteed to contain only unique elements, you can turn `list2` into a `set` and select from `list1` based on it:

```
set2 = set(list2)
list2_sorted = [x for x in list1 if x in set2]
```

If, on the other hand `list2` contains non-unique elements, you can use `collections.Counter` to do the same thing while maintaining optimal algorithmic complexity.

```
counter2 = Counter(list2)
list2_sorted = []
for x in list1:
    list2_sorted.extend([x] * counter2[x])
```

The algorithmic complexity is the same here because python's list growing is amortized to provide `O(n)` behavior in the long term, and the keys of a `Counter`, or any other `dict`, are implemented as a hash-table with `O(1)` lookup, just like a `set`.

You can use a nested comprehension instead of the loop:

```
list2_sorted = [x for x in list1 for _ in range(counter2[x])]
```

You can use the set-like behavior of dictionaries to maintain `O(n)` behavior even if `list1` contains duplicates, as long as the sort order is determined only by the first occurrence. In Python 3.6+ dictionaries are ordered, so you could use plain `dict`. Prior versions would require you to use `collections.OrderedDict` to obtain the same behavior:

```
list1_keys = OrderedDict.fromkeys(list1)
list2_sorted = [x for x in list1_keys for _ in range(counter2[x])]
```

The reason to use a `dict` when you are looking for `set`-like behavior is that `set` is not ordered.

Comment: That's quite cool too. What do you think it's O is?

Comment: @Nick. O(n)-ish depending on how you define n. It's a hash-table lookup for each element.

Comment: Yeah but you have to generate the hash table too... although I suppose that is also O(n)

Comment: @Nick. It is. The n has a large load factor, but it's about how it responds to larger inputs, not how practical it actually is.

Comment: @Nick. I've added an example for O(n) if both lists contain duplicates

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda function in `sorted`, taking `list1.index()` of the value to get a sort order:

```
list1 = ['Stella', 'Bob', 'Joe', 'Betty']

list2 = ['Joe', 'Stella']
sorted(list2, key=lambda v:list1.index(v))
```

Output:

```
['Stella', 'Joe']
```

Comment: This is O(n^2).

Comment: @MadPhysicist as is the accepted answer. If you have a better solution for a `list2` which may not be unique, please post it...

Comment: I've posted an answer. Thanks for pointing out this important corner case.